# Decoding Shapeless Tagged Types

Tags: scala, shapeless, circe

Given the following on Ammonite:

```
@ import $ivy.`io.circe::circe-core:0.9.0` 

@ import $ivy.`io.circe::circe-generic:0.9.0`                   

@ import $ivy.`com.chuusai::shapeless:2.3.3` 

@ import shapeless.tag 
import shapeless.tag

@ trait Foo 
defined trait Foo

@ import io.circe._, io.circe.generic.semiauto._ 
import io.circe._, io.circe.generic.semiauto._

@ import shapeless.tag.@@ 
import shapeless.tag.@@
```

Then, I attempted to define a generic tagged type decoder:

```
@ implicit def taggedTypeDecoder[A, B](implicit ev: Decoder[A]): Decoder[A @@ B] = 
    ev.map(tag[B][A](_)) 
defined function taggedTypeDecoder
```

It works when explicitly spelling out `String @@ Foo`:

```
@ val x: String @@ Foo = tag[Foo][String]("foo") 
x: String @@ Foo = "foo"

@ implicitly[Decoder[String @@ Foo]] 
res10: Decoder[String @@ Foo] = io.circe.Decoder$$anon$21@2b17bb37
```

But, when defining a type alias:

```
@ type FooTypeAlias = String @@ Foo 
defined type FooTypeAlias
```

It's not compiling:

```
@ implicitly[Decoder[FooTypeAlias]] 
cmd12.sc:1: diverging implicit expansion for type io.circe.Decoder[ammonite.$sess.cmd11.FooTypeAlias]
starting with method decodeTraversable in object Decoder
val res12 = implicitly[Decoder[FooTypeAlias]]
                      ^
Compilation Failed
```

Why is that? Is there a known "fix?"

Comment: Probably related to this issue: https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/8740

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lucky you, to hit two compiler bugs in the same day. This one is [scala/bug#8740](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/8740). The good? news is that there is a **partial** fix waiting around in [this comment](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/8740#issuecomment-292432768) for someone to step up and make a PR (maybe this is you). I believe it's partial because it looks like it will work for a specific tag but not for a generic one (I'm not 100% sure).

The reason why you see a diverging implicit expansion is really funny. The compiler can either expand all aliases in one step (essentially going from `FooTypeAlias |= String with Tagged[Foo]`) or not expand anything. So when it compares `String @@ Foo` and `A @@ B` it doesn't expand, because they match as is. But when it compares `FooTypeAlias` and `A @@ B` it expands both fully and it ends up in a situation where it has to compare refined types one of which contains type variables (see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48234902/2343787) to your other related question). Here our carefully crafted abstractions break down again and the order of constraints starts to matter. You as the programmer, looking at `A with Tagged[B] <:< String with Tagged[Foo]` know that the best match is `A =:= String` and `B =:= Foo`. However Scala will first compare `A <:< String` and `A <:< Tagged[Foo]` and it concludes that `A <:< Tagged[Foo] with String` (yes, in reverse) which leaves `Nothing` for `B`. But wait, we need an implicit `Decoder[A]`! - which sends us in a loop. So `A` got over-constrained and `B` got under-constrained.

**Edit:** It seems to work if we make `@@` abstract in order to prevent the compiler from dealiasing: [milessabin/shapeless#807](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/pull/807). But now it boxes and I can't make arrays work.